# Can I travel to the US on B1/B2 visa after I leave the sponsor company?

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, b1-b2-visas

My B1/B2 US visa is sponsored by my current employer and I am planning to leave to company now.

I want to know what will happen to my Visa if I leave the company and if I can still travel to the US for tourism and other purposes.

Comment: Are there any annotations on the visa?  If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "sponsored"?

Answer (score 5):

While nobody can guarantee anything and the final decision on admitting you to the country is up to the border patrol at the airport, this is generally fine. US B visas are issued to individuals with no requirement for corporate sponsorship. If your visa is valid for multiple entries and has not expired, you can use it for future visits to the US, as long as you comply with the terms of the visa.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you may have obtained the visa using details for (and the support of) a specific employer, B1/B2 visas are generally not "Sponsored". The visa is issued to you and not directly related to the employer, so as long as it is still valid then you are able to use it to travel to the US.

As with any time you enter the US (or any other country other than your own) you may be questioned about the purpose of the your visit, and potentially even denied entry to the country - however this would not occur simply due to you no longer working for for company that was involved in your initial visa application.  If you are no longer employed by any company then that may give the immigration staff more cause for concern around your intent in coming to the country, and the likelihood of you leaving at the end of your stay, but again the odds of this being an issue are low.

The one exception to this would be if your visa had any specific details, including the employers name, in the "Annotations" field. Annotations are additional notes/conditions regarding the issuance of the visa, and if your former employers name was mentioned in that section it may be an indicator that the visa was issued specifically for use with that employer.  Annotations on a B1/B2 visa are extremely rare, and it's unlikely that your visa has any - but if it does then they may change the answer above.